# Swift error: Reference to generic type Dictionary requires arguments in <...>

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, dictionary

The error `Reference to generic type Dictionary requires arguments in <...>` is appearing on the first line of the function. I am trying to have the function return an NSDictionary retrieved from an api. Anyone know what could be going on here?

```
class func getCurrentWeather(longitude: Float, latitude: Float)->Dictionary?{

let baseURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/\(apikey)/")
let forecastURL = NSURL(string: "\(longitude),\(latitude)", relativeToURL:baseURL)

let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(forecastURL!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

    if(error == nil) {
        println(location)
        let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL:location!)
        let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        return weatherDictionary
    }else{
        println("error!")
        return nil

    }
})
}
```

EDIT:

Second Issue:

```
    class func getCurrentWeather(longitude: Float, latitude: Float)->NSDictionary?{

    let baseURL = NSURL(string: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/\(apikey)/")
    let forecastURL = NSURL(string: "\(longitude),\(latitude)", relativeToURL:baseURL)

    let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(forecastURL!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if(error == nil) {
            println(location)
            let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL:location!)
            let weatherDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary


            return weatherDictionary //ERROR: NSDictionary not convertible to void

        }else{
            println("error!")
            return nil ERROR: Type void does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'

        }
    })
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are planning to return a Dictionary then you need to specify the type of key and data in it.

**Eg:** If your key and value both are Strings then you can write something like:

```
class func getCurrentWeather(longitude: Float, latitude: Float) -> Dictionary <String, String>?
{
   ...
}
```

If you are not sure about the data in it or if you have multiple type of data, change the return type from `Dictionary` to `NSDictionary`.

```
class func getCurrentWeather(longitude: Float, latitude: Float) -> NSDictionary?
{
    ...
}
```

**or**

You can write like:

```
class func getCurrentWeather(longitude: Float, latitude: Float) -> Dictionary <String, AnyObject>?
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved the first error but now I am getting a message saying 'NSDictionary' is not convertible to 'Void'. What do you think happened here?

Comment: @user1851782: Where did you get the error ? And what code you are using now ?

Comment: @user1851782: It's because of ` let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(forecastURL!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in` It's type is void and it's an asynchronous call

Comment: Oh wow that makes sense so I was returning from the closure not the function. Thanks!

Comment: @user1851782: Yes, also if you want to know how to return result from asynchronous function in swift (using completion handlers) check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Comment: “If you are not sure about the data...change the return type from `Dictionary` to `NSDictionary`” – this is not good advice.  If you aren’t sure about the type, you should figure it out, not use a type that doesn’t care.  That will just lead to more confusion later on.  If you genuinely need heterogenous storage, you should still use a Dictionary, with `Any` or `AnyObject`.  You should only use `NSDictionary` when you actually need an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: Can you say when I should use NSDictionary then ? `NSDictionary` is something similar to `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`

Comment: Yes – really I’m saying “don’t use AnyObject unless you absolutely have to” i.e. use a specific type, with a side-order of “don’t use NSObject unless you need to” – i.e. when interacting with a Obj-C API, or if it has a really useful feature you don’t want to do without.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: I agree with that case.